# Python TCP Server, others can't connect only localhost or my local IP

Tags: python, sockets

**My Server TCP Code:**

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = ''
PORT = 8031
s = socket.socket()

class BoServer:


    def __init__(self):
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except socket.error,msg:
            print "Unable to create socket"
            sys.exit()
        print "Socket created."
    def bind(self):
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        try:
            s.bind((HOST,PORT))
        except socket.error,msg:
            print "Bind failed. Closing..."
            sys.exit()
        print "Socket bound."
    def run(self):
         s.listen(10)
         print "Socket Listening"
         conn, addr = s.accept()
         print "Connected to %s:%s"%(addr[0],addr[1])
         while True:
            income = conn.recv(4096)
            if income != "":
                print income

def main():
    serv = BoServer()
    serv.bind()
    serv.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**My Client TCP Code:**

```
import socket
import sys


def main():
    host = ""
    port = 8031
    message = "Hello World!"

    host = raw_input("Enter IP: ")
    #Create Socket
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    except socket.error, msg:
        print "Failed to create socket. Error code: %s Error Message: %s"%(str(msg[0]),msg[1])
        sys.exit()
    print "Socket created"

    #Connect to server
    s.connect((host,port))

    while message != "/e":
        #Send Data
        message = raw_input("Send >> ")
        try:
            s.sendall(message)
        except socket.error, msg:
            print "ERROR %s"%(msg[1])
            print "Failed to send."
    s.close()

main()
```

I want to people write my public ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xx on the client and to connect at the server.

When I run the Server, others can't connect to my Server. I can only access the server with localhost or my local IP.

Everyone that tries to connect receive this ERROR:

```
Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you behind a router? Have you enabled port forwarding for port 8031?

Comment: Yes, already fowarded the port TCP - 8031 and with my firewall disabled.

Comment: How did you forward the port? Are you sure they are typing in your public IP? The code looks straightforward to me, it should work, so it has to be a configuration problem.

Comment: I tried you code and it worked with a remote computer. I think Thomas is right, it is a configuration problem.

Comment: It seems its only me then it must be my modem/router. Thanks for the help !

Comment: My router only have Port Triggering Option and not Port Forwarding, its the same ?

Comment: It worked now. It was a problem with my Router. Thanks